# Windows 8.1 thinks I have a touch screen

Tags: windows, touch, swipe

I have a problem - when accidentally launching any of *native* Windows apps and alt-tabbing to normal ones, then I have a hint (that occupies a fair quarter of the screen), that I can swipe between apps (screenshot is in Russian, but that's what it says).

**The things is that I know for sure that my display is not a touch-screen, so how can I persuade Windows into believing that?**
At the moment I have to reboot every time I got it (couldn't find any related process in the task manager to kill).
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried performing the suggested gestures with your mouse?  Windows 8 attempts to unify the UX between input devices.  (Or rather, it doesn't *think* you have a touch screen, in fact it doesn't *care* if you have a touch screen.  The UI elements are the same either way.)  Move the mouse to the corners to see some hints on what it's trying to show you.  There's a side-bar that's available on the left which can switch between Windows 8 style apps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a reply by @David.
You can move mouse to the upper left corner [to switch between apps], but also makes the swipe hint to hide.

Thanks, @David!